# wordpress - wp-includes\media.php on line 467

Tags: php, wordpress

Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open 'C:\Inetpub\vhosts\shahsteals.com\httpdocs//wp-content/uploads/2012/08/BRlogo-38431_120x136.jpg' for writing: Permission denied in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\shahsteals.com\httpdocs\wp-includes\media.php on line 467

i am using windows 2008 server

Comment: Have you checked file-system permissions on the directory? (owner and permissions)

Answer (score 0):

It appears some plugin or script is using linux "/" forward slashes for the path name. Whatever it is, it isn't suitable for Windows.